# Case-Sensitive Name Checker

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need help with an arrayformula that can look or check for names in a list based from a separate list of names.

The important part is it has to be **case-sensitive** and should return a "Not Found" error if it cannot find an exact match from a separate list.

[image: Case-Sensitive Name Checker]

In the sheet above, the separate list is in column F and it needs to check column B. The expected output is in column C. For row 3, "sean massey" should return a "Not Found" error because it can't find an exact case-sensitive match from column F.

IMPORTANT: There is an additional condition to this as well. I need the arrayformula to only be in **cell D2 only** and it will process the names in column B from top to bottom where column A is not empty.

Here is an editable sheet link anyone can use:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F8KaK3NqhYrUEM9Eo7VYl0DqLSvguJbHH81mY4dF-8U/

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regex is case sensitive. delete everything in your column and use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, F2:F)), "Found", "Not Found")))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, F2:F)&"$"), "Found", "Not Found")))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer bro. However if I add an additional letter in B2 (Sean Masseyy with 2 letter y's), it should output "Not Found" but it still says "Found". How to solve this?

Comment: @itsover9000 answer and your sheet updated

Comment: wow thank you bro. it's working. how did you do it? may I know how the formula works pls?

Comment: @itsover9000 sure: with `TEXTJOIN` we create a string `"^name1$|^name2$"` where `|` means OR, `^` means "beginning of string" and `$` means "ending of string" so what we get is: "exactly name1 or exactly name2"

Answer (score 3):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(A2="","",OR(EXACT($F$2:$F,B2)), "Found", TRUE, "Not Found"))` should work.

The first `IFS` condition checks if column A is empty. Then, the ArrayFormula is used with `EXACT` for case-sensitivity and `OR` to consolidate the resulting array into one Boolean value.

Comment: Is there a way to write the formula in one cell and it will automatically process all the other rows?

Comment: It is possible, although I'm not sure if it is with `EXACT` in my implementation. @player0's seems to work for this purpose though. Normally you would add this formula and drag down for each row of column B, but obviously that does not meet your additional condition.